# Codeigniter SQL Multipurpose Query

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Currently I am calling a title from the database using the below code it works fine but I am wanting to implement a view all area (pulling other rows from the `options` table) in my admin area for the main options for my website.

What would be the best way to do this?  Create another function for just the title? as I do not want to have a run a foreach loop just for the title.

```
function systemOptions()
{   

    $query = $this->db->get('options');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $query->row_array();

        $row['cms_name'];
    }

    return $row;
}
```

Comment: Why not just return all of the results and extract what you need from the result object when you need it?

Comment: @Colin How would I do that?  I know its easy but I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this;

```
<?php 

/*

CREATE TABLE `options` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
);

INSERT INTO `options` (`id`, `name`, `value`)
VALUES
(1, 'generic_keywords', 'This,is,my,generic.keywords'),
(2, 'generic_description', 'This is a brief site summary'),
(3, 'page_status_active', '1'),
(4, 'page_status_draft', '2'),
(5, 'page_status_invisible', '2'),
(6, 'page_status_archived', '4'),
(7, 'listing_length', '20'),
(8, 'page_status_deleted', '9');

*/



function systemOptions() { 

    $options = FALSE;
    $query = $this->db->get('options');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row) {
            $data = new StdClass;
            $data->{$row->name} = $value;
            $options[] = $data;
        }
    }

    return $options;
}

function systemOption($name) {

    $query = $this->db->get_where('options', array('name' => $name), 1);
    return ($query->num_rows() == 1) ? $query->row() : FALSE;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better return all the results in your model and extract it wherever you need an object as Colin said:

```
function systemOptions()
{   

    $query = $this->db->get('options');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $query->result();
    }

    return $row;
}
```

and if you want to use it in index method in controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data[row] = $this->example_model->systemOptions();
    $this->load->view('example_view', $data);
}
```

and use the code below wherever you need the object in your view file:

```
echo $row->cms_name;
echo $row->title;
```

Comment: Thanks but I get Message:  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: As I said, using echo `$row->cms_name;` and `echo row->title;` means that you can echo whatever column in your database. If you have cms_name in your database, then, retrieving `$row->cms_name;` wont put you in trouble. What are you echoing? and is that in your database?! Please share the line of the code which causes error.

Comment: and of course, don't forget to include $data in loading your view. `$this->load->view('example_view', $data);`

Comment: <?php echo $contentMangement->cms_name; ?> & $data['contentMangement'] = $this->options_model->systemOptions();

Comment: Do you want to get all the rows in cms_name column or you just want to get a specific data related to an ID ?!

Comment: and make sure that, you have put `$data['contentMangement'] = $this->options_model->systemOptions();` in your CONTROLLER, then include $data in loading your view file and require `<?php echo $contentMangement->cms_name; ?>` in your view. otherwise it wont work.

Comment: I want to get all rows and my comment above is how I have my C & V